# How i can filter some words of a statement with javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I wanna filter some words of a statement with javascript.
I have words must be filtered and words must be replaced :

```
var words = [
{'badword':/dog/, 'goodword':'1'},
{'badword':/gav/ , 'goodword':'5'},
{'badword':/folan/ , 'goodword':':6'}
// .
//.
//.
//and more
];
```

For Example I wanna /dog/ filter and 1 replaced.
How i can?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Could you perhaps rephrase?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to somehow transform some input string into some output string, based on some rules that you are defining in this javascript object?

Comment: How is this any different than your last question?

Comment: Yes @ChrisFarmer , my english is bad

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can search objects and use in variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236744/how-i-can-search-objects-and-use-in-variables). Please [edit your former question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21236744/edit) instead of re-asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/RF7Gm/1/

```
var text = "this is a dog called gav and a thing which is a folan here.";

var words = [
    {'badword':/dog/, 'goodword':'1'},
    {'badword':/gav/ , 'goodword':'5'},
    {'badword':/folan/ , 'goodword':':6'}
];

for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    var word = words[i];
    text = text.replace(word.badword, word.goodword);
};

alert(text);
```

Should output something like... `this is a 1 called 5 and a thing which is a :6 here.`

Comment: You're leaking a variable to the global scope.

Comment: whoops. should be fixed now ~ you are a very unforgiving crowd aren't you?